# Proving positive definiteness of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

If M is a real, invertible n x n matrix, how do I show that ${\langle a,b\rangle}=a^TM^TMb$ defines an inner product ($a$ and $b$ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$). I've proven that it satisfies the linearity and symmetry axioms, but I'm struggling to prove the positive definiteness axiom, where I need to prove that ${\langle a,a\rangle} > 0\ {\text{ if }}a\neq \mathbf {0}$.

Comment: Let $x:= Ma$. Then what is $x^Tx$ in terms of the coordinates of $x$, and when does it vanish? Now use $M$ invertible...

Comment: $$a^T M^T M a = \langle Ma; Ma \rangle >0$$ where $\langle .;. \rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product